# Jupyter upgrade changes data.frame presentation "A data.frame: 3 x 4"

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After upgrading to Jupyter Notebook 6.0, my R dataframes are now presented with information about type and dimensions - something like "A data.frame: 3 x 4".  How to disable that?  I want dataframes presented without information about type and dimensions.  Thanks for your help.

Dataframe presentation used to look like this (which is what I want):

```
    Date        Apple.Return    Dell.Return     IBM.Return
    1990.042    -0.035461       -0.1590909      0.04780877
    1990.125    0.003235        0.3513514       0.06550063
    1990.208    0.183824        0.2200000       0.02166065
```

Dataframe presentation now looks like this (which is not what I want):

```
    A data.frame: 3 × 4
    Date        Apple.Return    Dell.Return     IBM.Return
    <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
    1990.042    -0.035461       -0.1590909      0.04780877
    1990.125    0.003235        0.3513514       0.06550063
    1990.208    0.183824        0.2200000       0.02166065
```

Answer (score 2):

I've traced the cause of new data.frame rendering to the repr package, which gets loaded automatically in any new session.  repr version 0.19.2 renders a data.frame with no extra info (that's what I like).  repr version 1.0.1 renders a data.frame with a caption showing type and dimensions (that's what I don't like).

As a work around for now, I'll just explicitly install repr 0.19.2 on my system.  My next question would be how to ask repr 1.0.1 or a repr upgrade to disable the caption.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the behaviour has changed - I confirm it in a 5.7.0 notebook, don't want to do the archaeology to figure out when it changed.

If I put an explicit `print` statement in, I get the desired output (`print(dd, row.names=FALSE)` gets rid of the row names ...)  I don't know if there's a way to change the default display behaviour.

[image]

Comment: too bad, I might delete this non-answer then. FWIW I get the same behaviour you're reporting in a 5.7.0 Jupyter notebook ...

Comment: The past behavior (that I want) is reproducible on Jupyter Notebook 5.7.5 /  R 3.5.1.

The new behavior (that I don't want) is showing up on Jupyter Notebook 6.0.0 / R 3.6.1.

Comment: Huh.  I am using Jupyter Notebook 5.7.0/R development (so 3.6+ or 3.7). I'm surprised, though - I would expect this behaviour to be coded in Jupyter's rendering software, not in R.  I guess explicit `print()` statements don't solve your problem?